# Java Spring Convert whole GET Request to Custom DTO

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

According to the Spring documentation, you can receive all `GET` parameters in a map like so:

```
@GetMapping
public final ReturnType getAll(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> allRequestParams) {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible (and how) to also accept a custom Java object instead (for which a custom `Converter` exists via subclassing `GenericConverter`) in such a way that the Converter gets the whole request map for construction of its DTO object?

```
@GetMapping
public final ReturnType getAll(@RequestParam CustomDTO customObj) {
    [...]
}

[...]

@Component
public class CustomDTOConverter implements GenericConverter {

    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        // Allow MultiValueMap.class to CustomDTO.class
        [...]
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {

        final MultiValueMap<String, String> requestMap = (MultiValueMap<String, String>) source;
        // Construct CustomDTO from the requestMap
    }
}
```

Trying the above snippet will fail, complaining that there is no parameter `customObj` present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convert get parameters to java object use method parameter without annotations. CustomDto must have setters.

```
@GetMapping
public final ReturnType getAll(CustomDTO customObj) {
    ...
}

class CustomDto {
    int x;
    String s;

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

Url example:http://example.com/test?x=123&s=abc

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Have you tried it out yourself? Unfortunately, it does not seem to work for me, since the converter is not invoked at all, and the `customObj` is filled with `null` values.

Comment: Since my `CustomDTO` is very complex, I actually used implementing of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I came across this answer and tried it. It seems to work as expected.